# Creating an Excel Workbook with a Custom Ribbon

Tags: excel, vba, ribbon

i use this guide to creating an Excel Workbook with a Custom Ribbon:

https://bettersolutions.com/vba/ribbon/document-level-customui-editor.htm

There is a way to display the button that i create outside the tools bar?
i need to display the button on the center of the table in every excel file that will open.

Comment: Interesting. Can you post a screenshot of what you are trying to achieve? Feel free to use MS Paint if you need to ;)

Comment: In a word, no. Ribbon controls are always on the Ribbon.

Comment: @Rory. I could be wrong. From what I understood, the ribbon will only be used to "Enable/Disable" the "Showing of" button in the middle of the table. Something like turning of/on row/column highlighter?

Comment: @SiddharthRout I read *"There is a way to display the button that i create outside the tools bar?"* to mean that there is a button created via customui that the OP wants to show on a worksheet. I guess we'll find out. :)

Comment: No No @Rory. I am sure you are right and hence I said "I could be wrong" :)

Comment: @Rory: There is one more thought process. Using VSTO to not only create the ribbon but to rewrite the worksheet, change/selectionchange/activate to launch a button if the selection is within a table range... Let's see what the OP exactly wants...

Comment: This is exactly what I meant @SiddharthRout

Comment: In that case you have 2 options **1.** Use Custom UI editor to make that ribbon and in the ribbon button click event check if the current selection is withing a table or not. And if it then insert a button in the table **2.** Use VSTO to create the ribbon and in worksheet, change/selectionchange/activate event (in the add-in) insert a button if the selection is within a table range. **Note:** I mostly create Excel ribbons in VSTO for my clients. I find that much flexible and easier to manage.